# Javascript: import error and can't non find variable

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I downloaded this d3 JavaScript project from GitHub https://github.com/mcaule/d3-timeseries, and then I created an HTML page (index.html) to run the project. This is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./d3_timeseries.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./d3_timeseries.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/dist/create-example-data.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>

  <script>
    var data = createRandomData(80,[0,1000],0.01)
    var chart = d3_timeseries()
                  .addSerie(data,{x:'date',y:'n',diff:'n3'},{interpolate:'monotone',color:"#333"})
                  .width(820)
    chart('#chart')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a problem in d3_timeseries.js with this two errors:
[image]

NOTE: I don't want to use min files

Comment: Well, the problem is that you have to use the min-files of the dist folder. Give it a try.

Comment: Assuming sufficient browser support, you can change the `<script type="module" ...>` for the `d3_timeseries.js`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I don't think that will work because the import uses `from "d3"`, which the browser won't be able to understand since it isn't an actual address.  If it were something like `import * from "http://unpkg.com/d3@latest"` it could work, but it doesn't know how to resolve just `"d3"`.

Comment: @zero298 Since they downloaded the file, they'd be able to make that change.

Answer (score 1):

The exact file that you have linked, `d3_timeseries.js`, is not written in such a way that it can be used, without processing, in a browser.

Its very first line `import * as d3 from "d3";` will fail, no matter what browser, because `"d3"` is not a URL that can be evaluated correctly from a browser context.  It is not a relative URL, it is not a

It looks like it is intended to be utilized by webpack or some other script bundler.  If you used this in a webpack context to bundle your code, it would load `"d3"` from `node_modules`.

I know that you said that you "don't want to use min files", so your options are either compile your own bundle or just use the min files in the `/dist` folder.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The OP stated at the very end of their question that they don't want to use the min files which are the only files in the dist folder.  Ideally, they should build their own with minification disabled.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Sorry for the nit, but yeah the repo uses rollup as you can see by `rollup.config.js`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no problem.  And yeah, the OP could adjust the rollup config very easily to remove the uglification and produce a debugging build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you used the file in the `src` directory. This isn't a regular javascript file, it's node. Luckily the author is buidling what looks to be a web safe version in the `dist` folder. That version is minified, uglified, and ran through babel.

You rarely want to include files from `src` or files that aren't uglified. That will cause your webpage to load extra white space data that it does not need.

Comment: It's not "node", it's an ES6 module.